# Get multiple clock in and out time from multiple inputs and neglect without clock

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have login table structure as below

```
EmpId   Logdate                   status  
101     2021-04-01 06:54:35.000   in 
101     2021-04-01 11:54:35.000   out
101     2021-04-01 15:54:35.000   in
101     2021-04-01 23:54:35.000   out 
102     2021-04-01 06:54:35.000   in 
102     2021-04-01 12:54:35.000   in 
102     2021-04-01 11:54:35.000   out
```

I want to get like

```
EmpId   Logdate       in                        out
101     2021-04-01    2021-04-01 06:54:35.000   2021-04-01 11:54:35.000
101     2021-04-01    2021-04-01 15:54:35.000   2021-04-01 23:54:35.000
102     2021-04-01    2021-04-01 12:54:35.000   2021-04-01 11:54:35.000
```

Comment: Please provide the real "login table structure", and not only a list of values.

Comment: The last row of your expected result doesn't make sense - you can't log out before you log in, right? so it should be 06:54 - 11:54 and the row with 12:54 should be verbosed...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in my comment, I guess the last row in your result has the wrong login time. However, have a look on this approach:

```
DECLARE @t TABLE(
EmpID int,
LogDate datetime,
stat char(3)
)

INSERT INTO @t VALUES
(101,'2021-04-01 06:54:35.000','in')
,(101,'2021-04-01 11:54:35.000','out')
,(101,'2021-04-01 15:54:35.000','in')
,(101,'2021-04-01 23:54:35.000','out') 
,(102,'2021-04-01 06:54:35.000','in') 
,(102,'2021-04-01 12:54:35.000','in') 
,(102,'2021-04-01 11:54:35.000','out')

;WITH cteOut AS(
SELECT *
  FROM @t
  WHERE stat = 'out'
),
cteFilter AS(
SELECT o.*, i.LogDate AS LogDateIn, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY i.EmpID, o.LogDate ORDER BY i.LogDate DESC) AS srt
  FROM cteOut o
  LEFT JOIN @t i
    ON i.stat = 'in'
    AND i.EmpId = o.EmpId
    AND i.LogDate < o.LogDate
)
SELECT EmpId, LogDateIn, LogDate AS LogDateOut
  FROM cteFilter
  WHERE srt = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

It needed nested queries but it produces the end result

```
;WITH CTE AS (
    SELECT t.*,
          isnull(LEAD(status,1) over(order by EmpId),'out') as grp
    FROM Employee t
)
select EmpId,CONVERT(date, Logdate) AS Logdate,Logdate AS [in],endDate AS [out]
from
    (SELECT *,min(row_number) over(partition by EmpId order by EmpId) as minrow_number,max(row_number) over(partition by EmpId order by EmpId) as maxrow_number
    from
       (select t1.EmpId,t1.Logdate,t2.Logdate as endDate,row_number() over(partition by t1.EmpId order by t1.EmpId) as row_number 
        FROM 
           (Select * FROM CTE WHERE status = 'in' AND grp = 'out') t1
           join
           (Select * FROM Employee WHERE status = 'out') t2 on t1.EmpId = t2.EmpId) result) finalTable
where minrow_number = row_number or maxrow_number = row_number
```

result in sql: [https://dbfiddle.uk](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=f244e14d8a56192de52a5348a9f17fc2)